# Why Odoo12 says '404' for a file which is exactly where Odoo wants to be?

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, odoo-12

I was setting up Odoo12 on my local PC besides Odoo15 and I come across to an error which I don't know how to fix.

```
Mar 10 16:58:49 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:58:49,367 12598 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 12.0
Mar 10 16:58:49 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:58:49,368 12598 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo12.conf
Mar 10 16:58:49 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:58:49,368 12598 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home/thecowmilk/.local/share/Odoo/addons/12.0', '/home/thecowmilk/Development/odoo12/odoo/addons', '/home/thecowmilk/Development/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons', '/home/thecowmilk/Development/odoo12/odoo-custom-addons']
Mar 10 16:58:49 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:58:49,368 12598 INFO ? odoo: database: thecowmilk@default:default
Mar 10 16:58:49 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:58:49,456 12598 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
Mar 10 16:58:49 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:58:49,559 12598 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on masterit:8099
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,187 12598 INFO ? odoo.http: Generating nondb routing
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,268 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/database/selector HTTP/1.1" 200 - 2 0.012 0.099
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,302 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.010
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,314 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.022
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,316 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.022
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,325 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/util.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.004 0.016
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,326 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/popper/popper.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.026
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,329 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/index.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.004 0.029
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,333 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/alert.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.021
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,358 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/modal.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.015
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,360 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/button.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.001 0.019
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,369 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/collapse.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.001 0.026
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,370 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.026
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,371 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.027
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,371 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/carousel.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.001 0.029
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,379 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.009
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,381 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/popover.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.004 0.007
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,396 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tab.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.004
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,402 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/src/img/logo2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.005 0.006
Mar 10 16:59:00 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:00,508 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:00] "GET /web/static/src/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.005
Mar 10 16:59:08 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:08,938 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:08] "GET /web/database/selector HTTP/1.1" 200 - 2 0.013 0.064
Mar 10 16:59:08 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:08,970 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:08] "GET /web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.008
Mar 10 16:59:08 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:08,976 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:08] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.005 0.008
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,014 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/index.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.026
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,016 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/alert.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.026
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,018 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/popper/popper.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.027
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,023 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.008 0.031
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,021 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/util.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.030
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,020 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/button.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.027
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,072 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/popover.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.029
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,073 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/modal.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.028
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,073 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.029
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,074 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/carousel.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.032
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,074 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.028
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,076 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/collapse.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.032
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,099 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.002 0.006
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,106 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tab.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.010
Mar 10 16:59:09 masterit odoo12[12598]: 2022-03-10 15:59:09,120 12598 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022 15:59:09] "GET /web/static/src/img/logo2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 - 1 0.003 0.005
```

So many files are missing by an 404 Error code besides those files are there, present, in that directory. Can someone help me please? Config files are how they should be.

Comment: _those files are there, present, in that directory_ What directory?  `/web/static` is a url, not a directory.  When you configured the webserver, you should have told it what directory to use for static files requests.  Show us that configuration.

Comment: @JohnGordon https://pastebin.com/x1p93uay if you mean odoo12.conf here it is

Comment: @JohnGordon btw when I was setting up Odoo15 I just added the addons path and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

static files are served from filestore folder usually located at `/home/<USER>/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/<DB_NAME>` in case of ubuntu. Please check if this folder exists and there are subfloders in them. Also make sure not to use same db name for odoo-12 and odoo-15. This might mess up things.

Comment: Also note that it is much easier to use docker to manage multiple version of odoo. The will not be any version conflicts and life will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

add db_name=yourdbname in your .conf or in parameter.